# UIActivity and AVAsset data type usage

Tags: ios, facebook, uiactivity, avasset

According to the [UIActivity Class documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it is possible to add `AVAsset` objects as a datasource to `UIActivityTypePostToFacebook` activity. Does it mean that we can **post videos** using the standard `UIActivityTypePostToFacebook` activity type? If not then what kind of items can I post using `AVAsset` activity item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well.. According to *UIActivity.h*

```
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIActivityTypePostToFacebook   NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); // text, images, URLs
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIActivityTypePostToTwitter    NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); // text, images, URLs
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIActivityTypePostToWeibo      NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); // text, images, URLs
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIActivityTypeMessage          NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); // text
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIActivityTypeMail             NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); // text, image, file:// URLs
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIActivityTypePrint            NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); // image, NSData, file:// URL, UIPrintPageRenderer, UIPrintFormatter, UIPrintInfo
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); // text, image, NSURL, UIColor, NSDictionary
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIActivityTypeAssignToContact  NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); // image
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0); // image, video
```

videos are mentioned only in comments for `UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll`. This means that the only images can be added as AVAsset instances using these standard activity types.